# How to get HTTP request from JSON API to a table

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter

Current example code:

```
  child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
          child: Table(
            border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
            children: [
              TableRow(children: [
                TableCell(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text('Company Symbol'),
                      new Text(data['symbol'].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
              TableRow(children: [
                TableCell(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text('Name of Company'),
                      new Text(data['companyName'].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
              TableRow(children: [
                TableCell(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text('Exchnage'),
                      new Text(data['exchange'].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
              TableRow(children: [
                TableCell(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text('Industry'),
                      new Text(data['industry'].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ])
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
 }
 }'



Future<Map> loadData() async {
http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/company"),
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
return data;
}
```

[image]

**My problem is that I can't retrieve/get json values that are nested in the json/raw view.** 
if I use: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb&types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=5
as the url I can't get the same values. 
**What values do I need?**
  Example: 
`new Text(data['symbol'].toString()),`

**To get the symbol values in :**

{"quote":{"**symbol":"AAPL","companyName":"Apple Inc.","primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global** Select","sector":"Technology","calculationPrice":"close","open":165.42,"openTime":1545057000854,"close":163.94,"closeTime":1545080400475,"high":168.35,"low":162.73,"latestPrice":163.94,"latestSource":"Close","latestTime":"December 17, 2018","latestUpdate":1545080400475,"latestVolume":42949358,"iexRealtimePrice":null,"iexRealtimeSize":null,"iexLastUpdated":null,"delayedPrice":164.015,"delayedPriceTime":1545080393722,"extendedPrice":164.09,"extendedChange":0.15,"extendedChangePercent":0.00091,"extendedPriceTime":1545083995658,"previousClose":165.48,"change":-1.54,"changePercent":-

Comment: If you want to get only the symbol you could store the JSON object in a variable and then this would give you back the value for the symbol: myObj.AAPL.quote.symbol(myObj is the variable where you store the object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because first you need to extract the `AAPL` and `quote` json objects.

Replace your method with this and it should work:

```
    Future<Map> loadData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/company"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    Map data = json.decode(response.body);
    Map quote = data["AAPL"]["quote"];
    return quote;
    }
```

Update:

In case you want to loop for all your data, you can check this method below :

```
          _loadData() async {
            final response = await http.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb&types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=5");
            final Map<String,dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
            List dataList = List();
            data.keys.forEach((key){
               dataList.add(data[key]["quote"]);
            });

            dataList.forEach((data){
               final symbol = data["symbol"];
               final companyName = data["companyName"];
               print("symbol :$symbol , companyName : $companyName");
            });

            return dataList;
          }
```

Now you have a `dataList` variable which you can use to build your widgets .

Comment: correct. but instead from https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb&types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=5   in this case it would be more than 3 symbols.. and more data.